# Check for broadcasting compatibility in Tensorflow - C++ API

Tags: tensorflow

I am implementing element-wise operations in TensorFlow. Many TensorFlow operations, e.g. add, support broadcasting ([from numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html)). Broadcasting is possible if the following rule is respected:

> When operating on two tensors, their shapes should be compared element-wise. The procedure starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when they are equal, or one of them is 1. If these conditions are not met, an exception is thrown, indicating that the tensors have incompatible shapes. The size of the resulting tensor is the maximum size along each dimension of the input arrays.

Does TensorFlow **C++ API** provide any method for comparing the *compatibility* of two tensors? Or, which is the fastest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All element-wise binary operations' kernel implementations in TensorFlow derive from [`BinaryOpShared`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_ops_common.h#L36) class, that does the compatibility checking via the helper class [`BinaryOpState`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_ops_common.cc#L46). Perhaps, you can simply derive your kernel class from `BinaryOpShared` and get the compatibility checking for free.

Comment: I observed the following behavior that I am not sure to be correct. Given two tensors of sizes [3, 4] the BCast operator returns a new tensor of size [12]. Can you comment it?

Comment: When TF computes (x op y), where x and y have shape [3, 4] and op is a binary element-wise operator, TF first reshapes x and y to a 1-D tensor of shape [12], computes op in the 1-D dimension, then reshape the result back to [3, 4] as the final output.